# Trigger Play/Pause In Brower Through Headset

Tags: sound, shortcut-keys, pulseaudio, browser, headset

I usually use a browser to listen to music, but when I'm on my headset, I can't use the play/pause, previous, next buttons which is very annoying. I was wondering if there is a way I can do that. Although the play/pause buttons works wonderfully in audio players such as clementine, vlc, rhythmbox.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Each browser handles it differently. You could probably follow the steps here and instead of disabling the media keys, enable them: https://askubuntu.com/a/1220446/18665